# The Volatile Keyword and CPU Cache Coherence Protocol

Tags: java, caching, cpu, volatile, cpu-cache

The CPU has already guranteed the cache conherence by some protocols (like MESI). **Why do we also need `volatile` in some languages(like java) to keep the visibility between multithreads.**

The likely reason is those protocols aren't enabled when boot and must be triggered by some instructions like `LOCK`.

If really that, Why does not the CPU enable the protocol when boot?

Comment: No, MESI is always enabled when the caches are used. `volatile` is a *synchronize-with* relationship which implies an *happens-before* relationship which guarantee the correct ordering of *execution* of load and stores. It's about memory ordering, not cache coherence.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Volatile can also guarantee the visibility which is about cache coherence.

Comment: Yes, if not on x86 I suppose that's true. But I was under the impression you were talking about x86. And anyway cache coherence would be maintained by the OS, it's not something that happens on demand or under user space control.

Comment: why do you assume that the re-orderings otherwise would be done by the cpu _only_?

Comment: Cache coherence is a CPU concept. Visibility is a C/C++/Java concept. These are totally different. The cache coherence concept can only be used when doing low level programming either in asm or in C/C++ when using only volatile inter thread shared objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Volatile prevents 3 different flavors of problems:

- visibility
- reordering
- atomicity

I'm assuming X86..

First of all, caches on the X86 are always coherent. So it won't happen that after one CPU commits the store to some variable to the cache, another CPU will still load the old value for that variable. This is the domain of the MESI protocol.

Assuming that every put and get in the Java bytecode is translated (and not optimized away) to a store and a load on the CPU, then even without volatile, every get would see the most recent put to the same address.

The issue here is that the compiler (JIT in this case) has a lot of freedom to optimize code. For example if it detects that the same field is read in a loop, it could decide to hoist that variable out of the loop as is shown below.

```
 for(...){
       int tmp = a;
       println(tmp);
 }
```

After hoisting:

```
 int tmp = a;
 for(...){
       println(tmp);
 }
```

This is fine if that field is only touched by 1 thread. But if the field is updated by another thread, the first thread will never see the change. Using volatile prevents such visibility problems and this is effectively the behavior of:

- C style volatile
- the Java volatile before the Java memory model was introduced with JSR-133.
- A VarHandle with opaque access mode.

Then there is another very important aspect of volatile; volatile prevents that loads and stores to different addresses in the instruction stream executed by some CPU are reordered. The JIT compiler and the CPU have a lot of liberty to reorder loads and stores. Although on the X86 only older stores can be reordered with newer loads to a different address due to store buffers.

So imagine the following code:

```
int a;
volatile int b;

thread1:
    a=1;
    b=1;

thread2:
    if(b==1) print(a);
```

The fact that `b` is volatile prevents the store of `a=1` to jump after the store `b=1`. And it also prevents the load of `a` to jump in before  the load of `b`. So this way thread 2 is guaranteed to see `a=1`, when it reads `b=1`.

So using volatile, you can ensure that non volatile fields are visible to other threads.

If you want to understand how volatile works, I would suggest digging into the Java memory model which is expressed in synchronize-with and happens-before rules as Margeret Bloom already indicated. I have given some low level details, but in case of Java, it is best to work with this high level model instead of thinking in terms of hardware. Thinking exclusively in terms of hardware/fences is only for the experts, non portable and very fragile.

Comment: "caches on the X86 are always coherent" maybe not that correct. If without volatile,  thread A change the boolean variable `isDone` to true, but thread won't see that and will infinite loop with `while(isDone)`  . Using volatile can solve that problem. In hotspot source code, it use LOCK# instruction prefix, but I don't know how it work.

Comment: In the OpenJDK/Oracle JDK a 'lock addl %(rsp),0' is done after a volatile write to prevent older stores being reordered with newer loads; so it provides the [StoreLoad] barrier. This is only relevant to prevent reorderings of loads and stores to different addresses.

For more information see https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies

Comment: In the above example with the hoisting out of the loop you can see how the code can be transformed so that even on a system with a coherent cache, one thread doesn't need to see the changes made by another thread.

Comment: "_caches on the X86 are always coherent_" Not just on Intel compatible CPUs, but also on any CPU you will likely use anywhere when doing MT programming in any high level language like Java, or C++.

Comment: @HarrisonLee 
The issue with that code has never been cache coherency (unless older processors were not coherent by default), even LL/SC architectures are coherent (with more latency but eventually delivers the update).
The issue in that code was always the JIT compiler, if it misattributes the lack of variable alteration in the ThreadReader code as a signal that it should leave the boolean assignment ON TOP of the while, then the culprit is 100% the JIT optimization reordering, decoupling the boolean load from the while itself... it is NOT the cache's lack of coherency....

Comment: Processors which also reorder do not make this type of alteration and YET they still apply some form of reordering, so C and C++ are not affected by lack of fencing on the reading/load of spinlocks.
I've read comments trying to replicate the infinite loop error without any success, and I believe that JIT compilers are not decoupling the assignment from the while test (I hope not anymore).