# Do modern JIT compilers keep Program Order(PO) inside spinning loops?

Tags: multithreading, compiler-optimization, volatile, processor, spinlock

The consensus around here seems to be that the famous example given in the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book:

```java
public class NoVisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (!ready)
                Thread.yield();
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    } 
}
```

Can have 2 types of errors:

- Either `ReaderThread` prints 0 *or*
- `ReaderThread` gets stuck in an infinite loop

The fact of the matter is that Processors give NO ACTUAL access to alter latency speeds of their Cache Coherency(TM) protocols... so... all volatile does here is reordering...

Which means that:

- Not only "print 0" is because of reordering... but
  ALSO...
- The less obvious "stuck in an infinite loop" issue is NOT because of Cache
  Coherency(TM).. is because of reordering... to be precise a
  combination of 2 reorderings... the JIT reordering PLUS the processor
  runtime reordering.

So... after reading [this](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/) it seems to me the most logical way in which JIT compilers and processors OBEY volatile non-reordering semantics, is by keeping their instruction... position at place.

If a program order branch is composed of 200 instructions and a volatile write happens at instruction #34...everything above it and below it can be reordered... omitted... and even completely erased if redundancies are found, BUT the position of the volatile instruction "write" is kept in the exact same place...

**Nothing that was written ABOVE it can go BELLOW it, and vice versa.**

So how is the ReaderThread failing?
According to this 2 sources:
[video at 25:33](https://youtu.be/w2zaqhFczjY?si=zMmiByyYACJuOQQE&t=1533) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068297/11214643)

The compiler is looking at the Thread as a single unit to optimize... and if the value loaded inside the spin-lock is NOT changed through out the lifecycle of the spin, then the value is dereferenced from it's original register... and this is the thing that is preventing the Thread to read a proper value... because is reading a different register...

> The issue here is that the compiler (JIT in this case) has a lot of
> freedom to optimize code. For example if it detects that the same
> field is read in a loop, it could decide to hoist that variable out of
> the loop as is shown below.
>
> for(...){
> int tmp = a;
> println(tmp);  }
>
> After hoisting:
>
> int tmp = a;  for(...){
> println(tmp);  }

This is the thing... the Java Memory Model Pragmatics (transcript) states that the Thread code's PO is seen as independent from the entirety of the program...

> Here is where Program Order (PO) jumps in. To filter out the
> executions we can take to reason about the particular program, we have
> ***intra-thread consistency rules***, which eliminate all unrelated
> executions.

So, the optimization decides to do this because the WHOLE is not being seen, so from the perspective of the Thread nothing will ever change the captured reference.

In the `VarHandle` video, the solution is using `getOpaque` inside the spin... and this opens more questions... `getOpaque` does nothing it would be like reading the variable as being a normal variable without "volatile" keyword...
This makes absolute sense since Cache Coherency(TM) is not the issue... processors handle this immediately.

This means that the getOpaque solution is done for backwards compatibility... so that older JIT compilers see the getOpaque as a "volatile" and not damage the spinlock.

So there are 2 options I see modern JIT compilers are doing.

- Before intra-thread reordering, a previous inference is done on the
  WHOLE program, catching on potential reference changes... OR...
- Spinlock instructions are now reorganized/reordered from the loads happening inside
  it.

It seems because C and C++ never had these issues... as opposed to C#... that the reordering made by the Processor never destroyed these spinlocks...

So, my question is, Which strategy, are modern JIT compilers doing to not destroy the spinlock?

If I am wrong about something you are welcomed to correct it, thank you beforehand.

Comment: That's correct, compile-time hoisting of loads is the only thing that can cause a spin loop to spin forever if another thread really did store to the variable it's checking, because cache is coherent on all mainstream ISAs.  Same as in C.  ([MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/387181))  C's rule that data races are UB is precisely what allows it to hoist loads and other optimizations important for single-threaded code.  (Java doesn't have UB, but has rules about lack of visibility guarantees if nothing synchronizes between threads.)

Comment: (More precisely, [cache is coherent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) *between cores that we run C++ / Java threads across*.  There are boards with an ARM DSP and an ARM microcontroller that share memory non-coherently, for example.  But you don't run threads of the same Java program across those cores.)

Comment: According to [VarHandle get/setOpaque](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56342141) , Java `getOpaque` sounds something like C++ `volatile` - ordered at compile time wrt. other `volatile` accesses, and required to actually happen in asm, but no inter-thread memory-ordering guarantees so it's like `std::memory_order_relaxed` (well actually in ISO C++ a data race on a `volatile` is still undefined behaviour unless it's `volatile atomic<>`, but real compilers like GCC and clang define the semantics.)

Comment: So the question becomes in Java whether there's any guarantee about compile/JIT-time ordering wrt. other plain (non-volatile / non-opaque) operations in this thread, so e.g. if you're running on a machine with a strongly-ordered memory model like x86, whether you can get acquire/release semantics from `getOpaque` / `settOpaque`, like you could in Visual-C++ with `/volatile:ms`, which treats C++ `volatile` like `atomic<>` with `memory_order_acquire` (loads) or `release` (stores).  (Since MSVC's special volatile semantics did block compile-time reordering).

Comment: You say _It seems because C and C++ never had these issues... as opposed to C#._ But that's not the case. C and C++ has the same issues, and is implemented correctly in C and C++ by using compiler specific directives or hand written assembly code  to prevent re-ordering, perform atomic operations and control the CPU cache.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no JIT compilers do *global* analysis across all possible threads that might start to figure out if anything could sync-with a given load or store.  So they just locally order things strongly enough that any possible other thread observes things consistent with the language standard.  e.g. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html describes how that's done from C++ seq_cst (Java `volatile`) or C++ `acquire`/`release` to asm loads/stores on various ISAs.

Comment: @nos: You don't need to control CPU cache, it's coherent so you just need to order the accesses your thread makes to it, e.g. with a release store that can still reorder with later operations, but not earlier.  (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  This question phrased it somewhat clunkily, but when they say "Processors give NO ACTUAL access to alter latency speeds of their Cache Coherency(TM) protocols", they're saying that software couldn't break cache coherency even if it wanted to; a store being invisible to a load indefinitely is impossible in asm.

Comment: @nos: But yes, as for the rest of that statement, perhaps they mean that ISO C/C++ has never had something that promises order only at compile time but not run-time?  Except guarantees about volatile not reordering with other volatile, so two `volatile sig_atomic_t` variables will be in a consistent state if observed from a **signal handler** in the *same* thread, but not from other threads.  And C++11 std::atomic has `atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst)` which only gives compile-time ordering, not run-time.

Comment: Ok, what is the actual question you're asking.  You started talking about "spin-locks" at some point, but your `while (!ready)` on `private static boolean ready;` isn't even an attempt at a lock, it's just a broken spin-*wait* loop that isn't guaranteed to ever notice changes.  Is that what you're still talking about, how that naive code gets broken?  The JIT doesn't have to make any effort to look for writers in other threads because plain `int` means it can assume there aren't any.  Hoisting loads and discovering loop-invariants is useful in general for single-threaded code.

Comment: Are you actually asking anything about `getOpaque`?  If not, I'm not following why you brought it up.  And no, I'm not going to go watch a video about it as well as reading your stream-of-consciousness question.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes I've been reading your comments and No the video doesn't explain what that is. It seems terms like opaque are giving a brand new depth to the reordering activities done by the compiler, which involve other things beyond "what goes above don't put below"

Comment: I haven't said much because I'm not at home atm... but I'll do some research on opaqueness in memory models. Thanks.

Comment: [VarHandle get/setOpaque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73271955) seems informative, quoting the actual documentation (*Opaque operations are bitwise atomic and coherently ordered.*) and attempting to explain what that means.  So it sounds like it's basically C++ `std::memory_order_relaxed`, where the only compile-time reordering that's *not* allowed is with other operations on the same object (or across fences like `atomic_thread_fence(release)`).

Comment: Note that hoisting out of loops is still not allowed for `atomic<>` with `relaxed` in C++ because loads are still guaranteed to see stores in "finite" and "reasonable" amounts of time.  [Can and does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41820539) - it would be legal but compilers *don't* because even a finite amount of removal of loads (not hoisting out of a potentially infinite loop) is a step in that direction and could end up with surprising results.  So for now C++ compilers don't optimize even 2 relaxed loads of the same variable.